# Accessors on relationship not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, accessor

I have two models Cart and Products

On products model I have an'accessor: `amount`

```
$appends = ['amount'];

public function getAmountAttribute(){
    return $this->price * $this->taxe;
}
```

But when I'm trying to get amount from relationship like:

```
$cart = Cart::where('id',$uid)->with('products')->get();

foreach($cart as $row){
    print_r($row->products->amount);
}
```

It tell's me "Property [amount] does not exist on this collection instance."

What's the problem?

**UPDATE**

Cart relationship for products

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'id','product_id');
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing Cart -> Products is a hasMany, so you need to iterate through products.

Comment: Add ```protected``` after append property something like this ```protected $appends = ['amount'];```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `$row->products` a hasMany relationship? If yes, then $row->products returns a Collection instance and you have to loop through $row->products like,

```php
foreach($cart as $row){
    $row->products->each(function($product){
        print_r($product->amount);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over cart's products

```
foreach ($cart as $row) {

    foreach($row->products as $product) {
   
       dd($product->amount);

    }

}
```

---

In your case if you `dd($row->products)` inside the `foreach` you will get a Collection of Products which doesn't have a property `amount` so you need to iterate over `$cart->products` and get each product's amount